# Django App Dependency Cycle

Tags: python, django, dependencies

I am in the middle of developing a Django application, which has quite complicated models (it models a university - courses, modules, lectures, students etc.)

I have separated the project into apps, to make the whole thing more organised (apps are courses, schools, people, modules and timeperiods). I am having a problem whereby a model in one app may depend on a model in another - so I must import it. The second app then in turn depends on a model in the first, so there is a cycle and Python throws up an error.

How do people deal with this? I understand that apps should be relatively "independent", but in a system like this it doesn't make sense, for example, to use ContentTypes to link students to a module.

Does anyone have a similar project that could comment on this case?

Comment: Your scenario does not sound like one that apps were made for. The idea of apps is reusability (along with separate packaging, distribution, and versioning). You might save yourself some hassle by not forcing your topic areas into separate apps.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If your dependency is with foreign keys referencing models in other applications, you *don't* need to import the other model. You can use a string in your ForeignKey definition:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.ForeignKey('myotherapp.MyOtherModel')
```

This way there's no need to import MyOtherModel, so no circular reference. Django resolves the string internally, and it all works as expected.

Comment: Fantastic. This is exactly what I was looking for. Funnily enough I knew you could do this - as I use it in places where the ForeignKey references something that is defined later in the file, but I never thought of using it in this way. Thank you very much!

Comment: Was absolutely stuck trying to get models to validate until I found your post.  All it was giving me was Error: cannot import name <model> Thank you!

Comment: This fixes issues when deleting objects that have a FK relation in admin. I had to manually delete the related objects before completing the delete and this fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I wrote the following a long time ago. Reading it now, it is not good advice for the OP's question. They should probably just put their models into a single Django app. But the following is some general background on dependencies in code, and it mentions this "put them into one group" solution halfway through:

Ignoring the Django aspect to your question, the general technique for breaking circular dependencies is to break out one of the cross-referenced items into a new module. For example, the cycle:

```
moduleA: class1, class2
                       |        ^
                       v        |
moduleB: class3, class4
```

could become:

```
moduleB2:              class4
                                    |
                                    v
moduleA: class1, class2
                        |
                        v
moduleB1: class3
```

Or alternatively, you could split up the classes from moduleA:

```
moduleA1: class1
                       | 
                       v
moduleB: class3, class4
                                    |
                                    v
moduleA2:               class2
```

Or both:

```
moduleA1: class1
                       | 
                       v
moduleB1: class3

moduleB2:              class4
                                      |
                                      v
moduleA2               class2
```

Of course, this is no help if class A & B depend on each other:

```
moduleA: class1
                    |    ^
                    v    |
moduleB: class2
```

In that case, maybe they should be in the same module (I suspect this is the solution the OP should use. Put the various interrelated model classes into a single Django app):

```
moduleA: class1 <--->  class2
```

or maybe the classes can be broken down in some way. For example, perhaps a first step could be to break out the part of class1 that class2 needs, into a new class3, which both original classes depend upon:

```
moduleA: class1
                    |    |
                    |    v
moduleB:   |    class2
                    |     |
                    v    v
moduleC: class3(new!)
```

This has already broken the cycle. We might want to go one step further, and break out the part of class 2 that class 1 depends upon:

```
moduleA:       class1
                         |     |
                         |     |
moduleB:        |     |     class2
                         |     |      |    |
                         |     v     v   |
moduleC:       |    class3   |
                        |                   |
                        v                 v
moduleD:       class4(new!)
```

Sometimes this kind of breakdown is difficult. Getting the hang of it is certainly a skill that requires some effort to learn. If it doesn't go well, the resulting pieces seem very ad-hoc, specific to your problem, and you are left with a feeling that you have made your algorithm harder to understand by breaking it into multiple pieces. But when this process goes well, the resulting pieces feel like useful new primitives, which one could imagine being used elsewhere (even if that doesn't actually happen in your current project), and using them makes your core algorithm easier to understand.

(Remember in the general case, that the above "dependency" arrows could represent any kind of dependency between the classes, which might be inheritance, or composition, etc. One class method might simply call a static method on another class. And when we talk of "classes", all of this applies equally to other chunks of logic, such as functions which depend on (i.e. call) each other, or database tables that reference each other.

Answer (score 3):

If you're seeing circular model dependency I'm guessing that one of three things is happening:

- You've defined an inverse relationship to one that's already defined (for instance both course has many lectures and lecture has one course) which is redundant in django
- You have a model method in the wrong app
- You're providing functionality in a model method that ought to be in a manager

Maybe you could show us what's happening in these models and we can try to figure out why the problem is arising. Circular model dependency is rarely an indication that you need to combine two apps - it's more likely (though not definitely the case) that there's a problem with one of your model definitions.

p.s. I *am* working on a similar django application, but my app structure is probably quite different to your's. I'd be happy to give you a high-level description of it if you're interested.

Comment: Interesting. The problem I am having in detail, is that a Module (modules app) has a ForeignKey to Person (people app), for its students. TutorGroup in the people app then has a ForeignKey to Module - to assign a tutor group to a particular module. This is what's resulting in the dependency cycle. I can post a diagram of the models also if its still unclear.

I'd love to see the general structure of your project - it's really useful to see how others do things.

Comment: So is the relationship between Module and Person many-to-many (seems like it should be)? If so, you could define the relationship in Person with the related_name parameter set to 'students'. Then module_instance.students.all() would give you the queryset that I think you're looking for.

In my case, I don't have a Person model. I have two m2m relations from Course to User, one for students and another for teachers. Keeps it super simple.

Comment: Yeah it works with ManyToManyField's at present - and I could move it over to the Person model - but it just seems less "neat" - it makes sense to have it on the Module model. I have to have a "Person" as it extends Django's User, so I can add more functionality (like Job Descriptions etc.) I could have use profiles but this is simpler after some middleware I wrote to return People instead of Users :)

Answer (score 2):

Normally I advocate for splitting functionality into smaller apps, but a circular dependence between models reflects such a tight integration that you're probably not gaining much from the split and might just consider merging the apps.  If that results in an app that feels too large, there may be a way to make the split along a different axis, resulting in a more sane dependency graph.