# Crossed import in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, import

On example, i have 2 apps: alpha and beta
in alpha/models.py import of model from beta.models
and in beta/models.py import of model from alpha.models

manage.py validate says that ImportError: cannot import name ModelName

how to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django App Dependency Cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895454/django-app-dependency-cycle)

Answer (score 8):

I have had this issue in the past there are two models that refer to one another, i.e. using a `ForeignKey` field. There is a simple way to deal with it, per the [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself:

So in your beta/models.py model, you would have this:

```
class BetaModel(models.Model):
    alpha = models.ForeignKey('alpha.AlphaModel')
    ...
```

At this point, importing from alpha.models is not necessary.