# Django Models in Java-style File Structure

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a large Django application and would like to split my data models up in a 'class-per-file' structure, but in attempting to do so I'm running into circular dependency issues on some of the more complex models.

For example, I have three models, all in separate files:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sample_book = models.ForeignKey(Book)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    preferred_genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
```

Since Book depends on Genre and Genre depends on book, when I import Book anywhere, it would start a chain of circular model dependencies since each file imports the model from the other files. How can I avoid this? This is the kind of project that will grow very large very quickly so I don't want to just lump all of the models into one file.

Comment: Your question is similar to this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895454/django-app-dependency-cycle
It has solution too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django App Dependency Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895454/django-app-dependency-cycle)

Comment: (The above comment will probably come over as awkward, but it's the default you get when you vote for closing a question as duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also specify the model name as a string:

```
preferred_genre = models.ForeignKey("Genre")
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much. Also, thanks to codecool for pointing out the thread I missed in my search.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a design issue rather than a django issue.

Your Genre should not have a reference to Book. Otherwise you will create circular references whatever the language/framework you are using.

The sample_book seems to be for a feature of the application. I would propose maybe make an entity for storing the sample books you selected.

Or if the sample books is just a random book from all the Books, you could just have a function somewhere else that returns a book.

Comment: This is simply an example. The actual code is unfortunately confidential, so I'm unable to share it but the actual project is significantly more complex than this. While you might be correct on the specific example of sample_book, that was not really the point of the example. I was just trying to convey a similar problem for reference purposes.